# Element List Lone Entry Replacement

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Example list below.  All elements are in the form {1 or 0, 1 or 0, 1 or 0}, with a least one of the numbers 0 and 1 in the element (so excluding {1,1,1} and {0,0,0})

```
ListA = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, **{0, 1, 1}**, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1,
   0, 1}}
```

I want a command to replace any single lone entry in the sequence to be replaced with the next  sequence.

In List A the single lone entry is {0, 1, 1} as before this there are three {1, 1, 0} in a succession and following the single lone entry there are three {1, 0, 1} in a succession. So I want this lone entry to be replaced by {1, 0, 1}.

I want the command to be generic so can handle any combination of lone entries, I believe there will be 6 different scenarios (assuming the element sequence either side of the lone entry are different). Another example of lone entry of {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, **{1, 0, 1}**, {0, 1, 1},  {0, 1, 1}}

Lone entries at the start and end of the lists can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may construct a pattern with [`Longest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Longest.html) and utilise it with [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).

With

```
listA = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
listB = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}};
```

and

```
loneEntry = {s : Longest[a_ ..], b_, c___} :> {s, a, c}
```

Then

```
listA /. loneEntry
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}
> ```

```
listB /. loneEntry
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just for kicks:

```
f[{a__, a__, b__}] := a
f[{a__, b__, b__}] := b
f[{a__, b__, c__}] := c
{First@ListA} ~Join~ Map[f, Partition[ListA, 3, 1]] ~Join~ {Last@ListA}
```

> {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1,
>      0, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

Written for clarity over efficiency:

```
ListA =
  {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};

Split[ListA]

% //. {a___List, lone : {{__}}, b__List} :> {a, {b}[[1, {1}]], b}

Join @@ %
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 1}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}}
>
> {{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}}
>
> {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}
> ```

Other ideas:

```
sp = Split[ListA];

lone = Position[sp, {{__}}];
lone = DeleteCases[lone, {Length@sp}];

Scan[(sp[[#]] = sp[[# + 1, {1}]]) &, lone];

Join @@ sp
```

Or:

```
fill[{{{__}}, {x_List, ___List}}] := {x}
fill[{a_, b_}] := a

Join @@ Developer`PartitionMap[fill, Split@ListA, 2, 1, 1, {{}}]
```